# Pandas rank subset of rows based on condition column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, rank

I want to rank the below dataframe by `score`, only for rows where`condition` is `False`. The rest should have a rank of `NaN`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[34, 65, 12, 98, 5],[False, False, True, False, False]]).T, index=['A', 'B','C','D','E'], columns=['score', 'condition'])
```

The desired output with the (descending) conditional rank would be:

```
   score  condition  cond_rank
A     34          0     3 
B     65          0     2
C     12          1    NaN
D     98          0     1
E      5          0     4
```

I know `pd.DataFrame.rank()` can handle `NaN` for the values that are being ranked, but in cases where the conditioning is intended on another column/series, what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by condition column `rank`:

```
df['new'] = df.loc[~df['condition'].astype(bool), 'score'].rank()
print (df)
   score  condition  new
A     34          0  2.0
B     65          0  3.0
C     12          1  NaN
D     98          0  4.0
E      5          0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is `where` + `rank`.  Make sure you specify `ascending=False` or you'll get the incorrect output.

---

```
df['score'].where(df['condition'].eq(0)).rank(ascending=False)
```

```
A    3.0
B    2.0
C    NaN
D    1.0
E    4.0
Name: score, dtype: float64
```